# How To Identify Scroll Bar Position Using Selenium IDE

Tags: javascript, html, selenium, ide, scroll

Now, I know Selenium IDE doesn't have this functionality, hence I'm using the user-extension.js. Here's what my javascript code says.

```
Selenium.prototype.getToppos = function ()
{
  var Top;
  Top = window.pageYOffset;
  return Top;
}
```

And on my selenium IDE here's what i wrote

```
<tr>
<td>verifyToppos</td>
<td>0</td>
<td></td>
</tr>
```

Now the result is correct, which is 0, but after I checked around and play with the scroll bar, turns out this 0 is not from the website that I wanted to be checked. Instead it's checking the scroll bar position of the selenium IDE window. Is there anyway I can tell Selenium IDE that it is supposed to get the scroll position of the website that I open, and not the Selenium IDE window it self?

Comment: You'll probably need to use javascript to do that.

Comment: Do you know what's the javasciprt command to get the result that I wanted @Richard?

Answer (score 0):

I've done it with a simple `storeEval` command:

```
<!-- jump to the footer, and get the scroll position's Y co-ordinate offset -->
<tr>
    <td>click</td>
    <td>link=Skip to footer</td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>storeEval</td>
    <td>this.browserbot.getUserWindow().pageYOffset</td>
    <td>footerScrollPosition</td>
</tr>
```

In the `eval` commands, `this.browserbot` gets you the browser instance that is running your site, rather than the Selenium test runner browser instance.

You can then perform assertions on the resultant value with an `assertEval` command:

```
<!-- assert that the footer Y position is greater than the main content Y position -->
<tr>
    <td>assertEval</td>
    <td>${footerScrollPosition} > ${contentScrollPosition}</td>
    <td>true</td>
</tr>
```

(where I'd previously performed another `storeEval` to create the variable `currentScrollPosition`)

Does this work for you?